# 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception on visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, emgucv

I had a simple application to do face detection with EmguCv. I build that application with visual studio 2015. then yesterday I upgrade my Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017. And my application cannot running because EmguCv always throw an exception.

```
'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception
```

I check the CvExtern.dll and I am sure that I use right file with right processor architect. I also install Visual C++ redistributable 2008, 2010, 2013, 2017

can some one please help me , how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the answer. that is because my operating system is Windows 10 N. 
windows version N has restriction and limitation , one of the limitation is for image processing lib that makes cannot access the camera.

some references:
[reference 1](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2744809/difference-windows-pro-pro-home-home.html)
[reference 2](http://windowsreport.com/windows-10-n-edition/)